# Passing Value to HTML <input> tag

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I have this code to get the value from the dropdown list and showing the corresponding value to the HTML input tag. I dont know how to pass the values from the drop down the the HTML input tag. Please advise me to do this with the onChange method that when user select one of the values, the input tag gets updated.

my code is

```
function OnSelectionChange(str){     }

   $(function(){
    //show records
    $('#show').click(function(){
        $.post('data.php',
                            {action: "show", "hm":$('#headmark').val()},
                                      function(res){
            $('#result').html(res);
        });     
    });
});
</script>
<head>
<body>

<?php         
     $result = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT HEAD_MARK FROM FABRICATION');
     oci_execute($result);

     echo '<SELECT name="headmark" id="headmark"  onchange="OnSelectionChange(this.value)">'.'<br>';
     echo '<OPTION VALUE=" ">'."".'</OPTION>';

     while($row = oci_fetch_array($result,OCI_ASSOC)){
     $HM = $row ['HEAD_MARK'];
     echo "<OPTION VALUE='$HM'>$HM</OPTION>";
     }
     echo '</SELECT><br />';
 ?>

 <!-- MAX PLACEHOLDER SHOULD BE GATHERED FROM THE QUANTITY FROM THE   CORRESPONDING           HEAD_MARK-->
  Cutting: <input name="cutting" type="number" min="currCutting" max="currQty"     id="fcutting" /><br />

<h2>Show Records</h2>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<p>Result:</p>

<div id="result"></div>
```

and on the update_attribute.php is for querying the cutting value for passing to the min value in the input tag

```
 <?php

    $sql = "SELECT CUTTING FROM FABRICATION WHERE HEAD_MARK = '".$head_mark."'";

    $data_query = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

    oci_execute($data_query);

    while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($data_query)){

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store multi value in the OPTION tag, by using the [jquery.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function.

```
 $HM = $row ['HEAD_MARK'];
 $CT = $row ['CUTTING']; 
 echo "<OPTION VALUE='$HM' data-cutting='$CT'>$HM</OPTION>";
```

Then your js function should be like below

```
function OnSelectionChange(str){ 
     var ct = this.data('cutting');
     $('#fcutting').val(str);
     $('#fcutting').attr('min',ct);

}
```

Note : "data-cutting" must be lowercase in html tag.

Comment: I dont quite understand how to implement this. So the requirement is, getting the quantity and initial cutting value for the given headmark. once those 2 data grabbed, then put it into the input tag, like this   <input name="cutting" type="number" min="initialCutting" max="currentQuantity" id="fcutting" value="0"/>

It is because I need to set the lower and upper limit for the operator so that he wont messed up with the initial data.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking for

```
function OnSelectionChange(str){ 
     $('#fcutting').val(str);
}
```

where `fcutting` is the id of your given `<input>`

Comment: thats not what i meant, so the idea are,

1. getting the head_mark value from the dropdown list as the primary key
2. getting the QUANTITY and CUTTING value based on the headmark
3. send those 2 values back to the input tag like this, 
   <input name="cutting" type="number" min="initialCutting" max="currentQty" id="fcutting" value="0"/>
4. the min and max value will set the limit so the user wont mess up the initial values and not go over the quantity limit in the database.